# Returned content not displaying

Tags: 7, theming

I have created a custom page which has a db query to return content, which is using the pagerdefault extender on a Drupal 7 install.

However when I return the content the pager shows but not the content.  This is the code after the query:

```
$content = array();
foreach ($result AS $events)
{
    $content[] = '<div class=\'event\'>' . $events->type . ' - ' . $events->nid . ' - ' . $events->tutorial_start . $events->event_start . '</div>';
}
$build += $content;
$build['pager'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'pager',
    '#weight' => 1,
);
return $build;
```

I can see the $content rows if I dsm $build, but not display them on the page.  How do I render them on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you should know to make it works:

1. Your query should extend `PagerDefault`.
2. Element inside `content` should be **Rendered Array**

here is a working example adjust the code to your needs:

```
//- Build array
  $build = array();
  /**
   * @TODO: adjust the query to your needs.
   */
  //- Prepare the Query to Extend PagerDefault
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $nids = $query
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition('type', 'page')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();
  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    $content = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $event) {
      //- Prepare the content
      $content[] = array(
        '#type'   => 'markup',
        '#markup' => '<div class="event">' . $event->type . ' - ' . $event->nid . '</div>',
      );
    }
    //- Add Content to the build
    $build += $content;
    $build['pager'] = array(
      '#theme'  => 'pager',
      '#weight' => 5,
    );
  }
  return $build;
```

Comment: Ah thank you, that makes sense.  I was looking at the blog display code where it uses $build+= node_view_multiple() which must be already formatted in a render array.